# How to nag\ask user to enable permission until user gives it

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to nag user to give the location permission, since location is a key piece of functionality for the app.

I tried with checking on `onResume` for permission, but it doesn't give good results, user can switch back and forth between the app and the permission dialog can already be displayed.
I am thinking to use a flag to know that permission dialog is displayed, so something like this:

```
public void onResume(...)
{
   if(!isDialogDisplayed) 
   {
     isDialogDisplayed = true;
     // check for permission here
   }
}
```

I need to set `isDialogDisplayed` to `false` when dialog is dismissed.

I have doubts this is the best way to do this, any other ways to do this?

Comment: I think that's not the proper way to deal with the scenario where the user doesn't want to grant you a permission. You should consider telling your user why you need the permission before asking him for it. If he won't grant, rollback to before he tries to use the feature and ask again only if he tries to use it again.

Comment: @GabrielVasconcelos I agree with you except that in my scenario the app is continuously monitoring the location. The app won't work without the location permission. I really need the user to grant the permission.

Comment: Then the question is not whether you need the permission, but whether your user needs your app and knows what it is for. That being said, you could shut your app down and ask when the user tries to come back, or keep asking, but either way make sure to tell the user what's going on: Why you're asking again or why is the app shutting down.

Comment: Yes, I need to keep asking (I don't like the idea of 'shutting down app') and this is what I am trying to do, it's the reason of my question

Comment: What i mean is that simply popping up the dialog again and again might not be the ideal scenario.

Comment: @GabrielVasconcelos Why isn't an ideal scenario? What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your MainActivity's onStart method, run this method:

```
private void checkForPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
    } else {
        initializeViews();
    }
}
```

*initializeViews()* is to make your app start up like normal.

Then implement the *onRequestPermissionsResult()* as below:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            initializeFragments();
        } else {
            openAlertDialog();
        }
    } 
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

**MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION** is a final int field, which in my case is 100. The value does not matter, as long as you use the same variable in both methods.

If the user did not allow the permission, *openAlertDialog()* will be called, which in my app is the following:

```
private void openAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("This app requires your location to function!");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Try again",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    checkForPermissions();
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("package:dk.redweb.intern.findetlokum"));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

This method makes a dialog window, where the user will be given a choice between getting the permission request again, or opening up the Settings menu for your app. When the user returns to the app from Settings, onStart will be called again to check if the permission has been granted.

Comment: This won't work in the case when user checked "Remember" option and hit Deny on the permission dialog. There will be no permission dialog showed again when calling to display it.

Comment: If the user has checked Remember, then you cannot really do much. Perhaps change the Dialog Button to direct him to the Settings menu where he can change it?

Comment: Yes, direct user to the Setting menu. But when he goes back to the app, I need to check again. So here's where `onResume` comes into play...

Comment: so call the *checkForPermissions()* in your onResume.

Comment: When user clicks the "Show settings" button, two things will happen: the dialog is going to closed (activity resumed) and app settings are shown (which puts activity in the background). I hope the 2nd is done first, otherwise I am going to get the dialog asking for permission when user goes back to the app. I need to try it.

Comment: Good point. When I have *checkForPermissions()* in my onResume it goes into a loop. However, if I have the check method in onCreate and onStart, that seems to do the trick when the user is coming back from Settings.

Comment: Update: By only having the call in onStart, asks once and does not pop up again after user returns from settings, unless he did not change the permissions.

Comment: Can you update code to show it works with `onResume` please? Other people can benefit from it too? Thanks